# How do I account for the selection of the 13th individual that can be from a random group?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, combinations

**Question:**
Suppose a thirteen-member student government council is to be comprised of at least three students from each of the four classes: freshmen, sophomores, juniors and seniors. Moreover, suppose nine candidates from each of the four classes have been nominated. How many different thirteen-member councils can be formed? Note that everyone in the thirteen-member council has the same statues.

**Possible Solutions?**

- 9C3^4 x 24C1 > but am i overcounting the total no. of individuals?
- should i choose the class where the extra person will come from first so 4C1 x 9C3^3 x 9C4?

Comment: Yes, you should choose the class of the "extra person" first.  There's no way, after the fact, to distinguish the extra person from the others in their class and this causes over counting.

Comment: Worth noting:  in this particular case it doesn't hurt you much to do it the other way.  As there are $4$ people in the over-represented class, you count each configuration $4$ times (depending on which of the four you call the extra one).  Thus to correct the overcounting you can simply divide by $4$.  Usually, however, this sort of method gets you in more serious trouble.

Comment: @lulu can i check with you why this sort of method gets you in trouble in usual cases? thanks!

Comment: [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4363335/why-is-this-probability-equation-wrong) is a recently asked question where the OP makes the same mistake you did, but in this case you can't correct with a single factor (the OP counts each $AAAO$ three times and each $AAAA$ six times).